# How can I pass a parameter based on if the user is in a role to an extension from Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following:

```
@Html.NavLinks(@Model.menuItems, (string)ViewBag.FilePath)
```

Now I would like to add another parameter that's based on the user's role

```
User.IsInRole("Admin")
User.IsInRole("Guest1")
User.IsInRole("Guest2")
```

Is there an easy way I could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the info you provide I can think of extending the helper NavLink in one of two way:

1. Add a parameter for passing user's role
2. Passing only a parameter of type class/interface containing all the fields your method needs

Comment: Would it be possible to pass the user into the helper and if I did that then could I still do an IsInRole check from there?

Comment: Why not. If you pass the instance of the user you should be able to call User.IsInRole as you do outside the helper